# End a program with the Enter key

Tags: c, exit

I am trying have a program end when the user hits the Enter key. For some reason it doesn't seem to work. When I use "char c is not equal to enter key" it takes in an extra integer in c (the last inputted integer). What is the problem with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define framenumber 4

int test1 =0;
int test2=1;
int main(void)
{
    int mainarray[framenumber][2] = {0}, nHP = 3, takein, iPT;
    char c = getchar();
    printf("Enter: ");
    while(1)
    {
        char c = getchar();

        if(c == '\n') {
            printf("here");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("not enter\n");        

            takein = atoi(&c);

            for (iPT = 0; mainarray[iPT][test2] != takein && iPT < framenumber; iPT++);

            if (mainarray[iPT][test2] != takein)
            {
                //search for a victim
                do {
                    nHP = (nHP + 1) % framenumber;
                } while ( !( mainarray[nHP][test1] == 1 ? mainarray[nHP][test1] = 0 : 1 ) );
                //update the page table
                mainarray[nHP][test1] = 1;
                mainarray[nHP][test2] = takein;
            }
            else
            {
                mainarray[iPT][test1] = 1;
            }

            puts("page table:");
            for (iPT = 0; iPT < framenumber; iPT++)
            {
                printf("%s %d, %d.\n", iPT == (nHP + 1) % 4 ? ">": " ", mainarray[iPT][test1], mainarray[iPT][test2]);
            }
            putchar('\n');

            printf("Enter: ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On what operating system? Your `printf` should have an ending newline in their format (or else use `fflush`). On Linux, you should read about tty-s. The terminal is read line by line...

Comment: Mac osx . how do i use fflush? thanks

Comment: MacOSX is also a unix system, so you also should read about http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php ; and you could call `fflush(NULL);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not create block variable. (In while loop).

```
  char c='\0';      /* initialize with 0 */
  printf("Enter: ");
  while(c!='\n')   /* loop terminate condition */
   {
        c= getchar(); /* remove declaration  */
        if(c =='\n')
        {
        printf("here");
        }
        else
        {
        getchar();  /*  read (eat) an extra input  */
        printf("not enter\n");
    ....
```

Comment: The program ends if i put a two or more digit number (obviously since we are doing get char()), any easy way to fix this ?? :O

Comment: No, because you're calling atoi on &c. atoi expects a zero terminated string.

Comment: Okay  I changed some things now I am getting my input using scanf and change my input to integer type but now it detects the enter key but since the ascii of enter is 10 it exits even when i input number 10. any suggestions for this ?

Comment: @RohitDeshmukh - Take a look at this thread if you want to input string (two or more digits) - http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/36496-mygets.html

Comment: I am going crazy trying to get solutions in different ways. This is what i am trying to do I want to take in integers (can be two or more digits) and when the user enters the enter key the program exits. Could someone please please please give me a code chunk for this or a link or something :/